# How many websockets connections will be established during one program run?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

I want to use the websockets library (python) more efficiently, so I also use asyncio lib, and in all guides it writes that it's needed to write `async with websockets.connect(_websocket_uri) as websocket:`.

But it's not clear whether a new connection is created every time program call `async with websockets.connect(_websocket_uri) as websocket:`? And how often do it generally call this line? There's a fear that due to the stream spamming for no reason, I will be banned.

I don't fully understand how the `asyncio` lib works. So I don’t know how often the program asynchronously enters this specific line. I need the connection to be established only once for the entire time the program is running (to avoid stream spamming), but how it's now I'm not at all sure.

---

Full code:

```
async def fetch_data(_websocket: WebSocketClientProtocol) -> None:
    async for message in _websocket:
        print(json.loads(message)['data']['s'])


async def connect_to_single_uri(_connection_uri: str) -> None:
    async with websockets.connect(_connection_uri, max_queue=None) as connected_websocket:
        await fetch_data(connected_websocket)


async def connect_to_streams(_connection_uris: Set) -> None:
    await asyncio.wait([
        connect_to_single_uri(websocket_uri) for websocket_uri in _connection_uris
    ])


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(connect_to_streams(websocket_uris))
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Yes, ``connect`` creates a connection – that's it point. But as for how often it is called – as often as *you* tell your code to call it.

Comment: That's all code. I don't fully understand how the asyncio lib works. So I don’t know how often the program asynchronously enters this line. I need the connection to be established only once for the entire time the program is running (to avoid stream spamming), but how it's now I am not at all sure

Comment: The code as shown will execute ``connect`` once for every URI – same as a synchronous program of the same structure would do.

Comment: Ah, ok, then it's good if for one run the program won't establish more than one connection for a unique uri